# How to Cache a Collection of objects in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api

I'm very new to Asp.Net Web APIs (which Microsoft has made a part of MVC templates though we can use Web API template independent of MVC).... Just a little background.

Coming back to my problem when my Web Service is called by a user then along the line of what my Web Service is serving comes a point where I have to deserialize a JSON file to a generic C# collection and cache it in-memory and then the code inside one of the Controller actions (which is obviously a get method) checks for the in-memory cache and if it has that deserialized C# collection it gets it from there else its calls another method inside the controller which caches this generic collection in memory.

My question is ... is this possible to cache the stuff for a Web API like what I described above...I'm quite familiar with Asp.Net page life cycle, caching and sessions etc. But not with Web API.... And my above explanation is just an abstract idea... not sure how to execute it, will it work? If yes then what namespaces would come in handy like `System.Runtime.Caching` or `System.Web.Caching`.
Your answers will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET Framework 3.5 and earlier versions, ASP.NET provided an in-memory cache implementation in the System.Web.Caching namespace. In previous versions of the .NET Framework, caching was available only in the System.Web namespace and therefore required a dependency on ASP.NET classes. In the .NET Framework 4, the System.Runtime.Caching namespace contains APIs that are designed for both Web and non-Web applications. ASP.NET Web API doesn't have dependency in System.Web.dll so I recommend you to using System.Runtime.Caching, you can put your caching logic anywhere even in separate .dll file and use it in your ASP.NET Web API project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.It sounds i got what i need.